# Eclipse e4 RCP minimize/maximize missing on view parts?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, minimize, maximize, e4

When creating an RCP application using Eclipse Juno (e4 platform), view parts do not provide the minimize/maximize toolbar actions.

What is also missing is the double-click action on the view part header which would minimize and maximize the view accordingly.

I also noticed, that the header bar of a view part is slighly lower than it was in previous releases, such that an action button doesn't really fit in it (drawn over the border of the header - see image).

I just created the example RCP app providing a simple intro page.

[Screenshot of defect view part in e4](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53933110/viewpartDefect_e4.png)

[Screenshot of correct view part in Ganymede](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53933110/viewpartOk_Ganymede.png)

It seems to me like a bug on e4 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: See this http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/11/13/rcp-minimize-maximize-view/

Comment: @tostao i dont' want to remove these buttons. they are simply not there - but they should be.

Comment: Could you show settings for this view (plugin.xml).

Comment: @tostao it is not view specific - it appears on any view. just run one of the rcp examples shipped with Eclipse and see it yourself. I am using Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issues. I followed the options on this link for migrating from 3.x to 4.x and it worked for me.
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/06/18/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/
Basically added the following as dependency to my plugin and run configuration.

- org.eclipse.equinox.ds
- org.eclipse.equinox.event
- org.eclipse.equinox.util
- org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt